# Type GetTypeFromCLSID (Guid clsid, string server ) - can I use IP for server name?

Tags: c#, .net, com

```
var myGuid = new Guid("530A1815-820C-11D3-BBB7-008048DE406A");
var myType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid, "somePCname");
```

Do I need to specify server netbios name or I can use server IP address?

Can I do like this?

```
var myType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(myGuid, "192.168.1.109");
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did it work with an IP address?

Comment: At this moment I can't even try, I'm asking because I need code first and test this far away from my work place)

Comment: Put two backslashes in front of the IP address to turn it into a server name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is: yes we can use an IP